# how to modify the dropdown text onchange event and onclick when the select box expands should have original value

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Here is the dropdown i have, if i select 2.0 then the text should be changed to "Android 2.0", I can display the text using the value. But i need to know how to reset the value back to 2.0 when onclick ( ie on expanding the dropdown). This does not work in IE browsers.

```
<div id="select_id">
   <select name="androidSelect" >
     <option value="">Select Option</option>
     <option value="Android">Android</option>
     <option value="Android 2.0">2.0</option>
     <option value="Android 3.0">3.0</option>
     <option value="IPhone">IPhone</option>
     <option value=" IPhone 2.0">2.0</option>
     <option value=" IPhone 3.0">3.0</option>
     <option value=" IPhone 4.0">4.0</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What doesn't work in IE browsers? Please post the code you're using.

Answer (score 2):

Store the name as a data attribute along with the value so you can switch back and forth between them:

`<option value="Android 2.0" data-name="2.0">2.0</option>`

Comment: +1 we got the same idea, but I think it can be optimized further

Answer (score 0):

**[updated]**

here you go

```
<div id="select_id">
   <select name="androidSelect" >
     <option value="Select Option" orig="Select Option">Select Option</option>
     <optgroup label="Android"></optgroup>
     <option value="Android 2.0" orig="2.0">2.0</option>
     <option value="Android 3.0" orig="3.0">3.0</option>
     <optgroup label="IPhone"></optgroup>
     <option value=" IPhone 2.0" orig="2.0">2.0</option>
     <option value=" IPhone 3.0" orig="3.0">3.0</option>
     <option value=" IPhone 4.0" orig="4.0">4.0</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('[name="androidSelect"]').change(function(){
    var i = $(this)[0].selectedIndex ; 
    console.log(i);
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('orig'));
    });
    $(this).children('option:eq('+i+')').html(x);
    console.log($(this).children(':eq('+i+')'));
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/vPnqP/)**

**[update] :**

js:

```
$('[name="androidSelect"]').change(function(){
    var i = $(this)[0].selectedIndex ; 
    console.log(i);
    var x = $(this).val();
    $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('orig'));
    });
    $(this).children('option:eq('+i+')').html(x);
    console.log($(this).children(':eq('+i+')'));
}).mousedown(function(){
    $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('orig'));
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/vPnqP/1/)**

This still can be optimized ..

Comment: Hi CME64, Thanks for your coding, I still need the original value onclick of select box (ie in the expand mode, i need the original value) eg: if i select 3.0 under iphone, then the display should be "iphone 3.0" then if i click the select box, on expanded mode the text should be back to 3.0.

Comment: you're welcome, that can be done too, i figured this way is easier for you to handle, you still can use the same method and instead of reading the value on click, read the selected option's attribute "orig" which contains the original value

Comment: ok I misunderstood you,, add this line in  the mousedown event $(this).children('option').each(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).attr('orig'));
    });

Comment: you can also force trigger 'change' event in blur event

Comment: After modifying the code it works fine in all the browsers except in IE browsers. http://jsfiddle.net/RNYwF/2/ Let me know how to make this work in IE browsers

Comment: I don't see any modifications other that **reselecting** the dom again to bind the mousedown to it which you should avoid to increase the effeciency .. on IE, remove the mousedown event and all will be fine .. glad I could help

Comment: better add .blur(function(){ $(this).change();}); instead

Comment: If i add blur event, then onclick i get the selected value "android 2.0" instead of 2.0 in the expanded drop down. IF i add mosuedown then it does not work in the IE browsers. not even the value is changed in the dropdown. Is there any other possibilities.

Comment: Yes I think you can't change that, IE has a different handling than other browsers to lists, I guess that's due to the new list dynamics ( win8 theme) because mouse controls are bound to that list as it appears and if you try to use them they will affect the list functionality. you have to find another event for that to handle the IE that's all. or just leave it break on IE who uses it anyways !